# Evenly Space DIVs Vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have HTML that looks like the following:

```
<div class="page-break">  
   <div class="menu-item-div">
      <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
   </div>

   <div class="menu-item-div">
      <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
   </div>

   <div class="menu-item-div">
      <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Each `.menu-item-div` I need to be evenly spaced apart *vertically* to fill the div's height. The div `.page-break` does have a set height of 210mm.

Each `.page-break` div will have a different number of `.menu-item-div` within it. I need to be able to equally space these divs vertically but stay contained within the `.page-break` div's height of 210mm.

A solution using flexbox is fine, I just don't know flexbox enough to do this.
Another requirement is these divs will be printed and it has to work when printed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B - Good information. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set the following properties on the container

```
.page-break {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rpxxo5h9/2/)

```css
.page-break {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.menu-item-div {
  background: tomato;
  height: 40px;
  /* If there was real content in the markup this would not be necessary */
}
```

```html
<div class="page-break">
  <div class="menu-item-div">
    <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item-div">
    <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
  </div>

  <div class="menu-item-div">
    <!-- CONTENT WITHIN DIV -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I control the justify-content spacing?