# How would I align buttons and images next to each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have been testing and looking for ways for this to work. I used this question as help, but now I cannot get the images to be to the right of the payment method buttons.

[Evenly Space DIVs Vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988242/evenly-space-divs-vertically)

Here is my code:

```css
.right-column {
  background-color:#f6f7f9;
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
  height:1078px;
        padding:15px;
 }
 .row-heading {
  text-align:center;
  padding:0;
 }
 .payment-img {
  width:84px;
  height:100%;
        padding:0 0 0 15px;
 }
 .paypal-payment {
  width:150px;
  height:45px;
 }
 .cash-payment {
 }
 .payment-rows {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
 }
 .payment-form {
  padding:0;
 }
 .payment-method-checkbox {
  padding:50px 0 0 0;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 .payment-method {
  border:1px solid white;
  background-color:#4ab847;
  color:white;
  height:35px;
  width:100%;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
 }
 .payment-method:hover, .payment-method:focus, .payment-method:active {
  color: #4DB748;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #4DB748;
 }
 .terms-conditions {
  color:dodgerblue;
 }
 .right-column {
  height:501px;
 }
 .row-heading {
  font-size:22px;
 }
 .reservation_summary, .total_costs {
  font-size:22px;
 }
 .div-btn-paypal, .div-btn-cash, .div-btn-visa  {
        padding:0;
 }
    .visa-payment {
        padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 right-column" style="float:right;">
        <h2 class="row-heading">Please Select a Payment Method to Pay for your Reservation</h2>
        <div class="payment-form">
            <form class="payment-form-start" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 div-btn-paypal">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="PayPal">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="payment-img paypal-payment" src="https://www.pastepic.xyz/images/2020/03/03/pay_pal65b5eab2fcbb7421.png">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 div-btn-cash">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="Cash">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="payment-img cash-payment" src="https://www.pastepic.xyz/images/2020/03/03/cash3e374265160bbca9.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 div-btn-visa">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="MasterCard/Visa">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 visa-payment">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/maestro.png">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/mastercard.png">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/visa.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 payment-method-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="payment-method-checkbox" required="">
                    <span>I have read, and I agree to the <a href="https://www.amitours.rent/terms-and-conditions" class="terms-conditions" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I haven't read and don't agree to the Terms & Conditions . On a serious note please share also the HTML so we can reproduce your current situation

Comment: I entered my html code, it isn't showing up.

Comment: I edited your question with a code snippet. Please use this in the future. Is the `[<>]` button in the edit toolbar. Is this your current situation ?

Comment: This is my current situation. But the buttons aren't as wide as it is showing in the code snippet.

Comment: So it's NOT your current situation then. Are you using bootstrap ? Because i see some bootstrap classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of logic problems.

Your buttons are inside a div with class `col-12` which means 100% width. ( bootstrap class ).  Solution : use `col-8` on buttons and `col-4` on images. Or other classes that when added equal 12. ( 10+2, 9+3, 8+4 and so on )

Then, you use `flex-direction: column` on the `payment-row`. You need to set `row` or leave empty because row is default.

You will also need to tweak the css a little bit.

Also. Do not use `float` for layout. Especially when you are already using bootstrap which uses flexbox. And make use of boostrap classes like `row` on rows and `.container` and so on

Read more about bootstrap grid system here -> [bs grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Read more about about flexbox -> [flexbox MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.right-column {
  background-color:#f6f7f9;
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
  height:1078px;
        padding:15px;
 }
 .row-heading {
  text-align:center;
  padding:0;
 }
 .payment-img {
  width:84px;
  height:100%;
        padding:0 0 0 15px;
 }
 .paypal-payment {
  width:150px;
  height:45px;
 }
 .cash-payment {
 }
 .payment-rows {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
 }
 .payment-form {
  padding:0;
 }
 .payment-method-checkbox {
  padding:50px 0 0 0;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 .payment-method {
  border:1px solid white;
  background-color:#4ab847;
  color:white;
  height:35px;
  width:100%;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
 }
 .payment-method:hover, .payment-method:focus, .payment-method:active {
  color: #4DB748;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #4DB748;
 }
 .terms-conditions {
  color:dodgerblue;
 }
 .right-column {
  height:501px;
 }
 .row-heading {
  font-size:22px;
 }
 .reservation_summary, .total_costs {
  font-size:22px;
 }
 .div-btn-paypal, .div-btn-cash, .div-btn-visa  {
        padding:0;
 }
    .visa-payment {
        padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 right-column" style="float:right;">
        <h2 class="row-heading">Please Select a Payment Method to Pay for your Reservation</h2>
        <div class="payment-form ">
            <form class="payment-form-start" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-3 div-btn-paypal">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="PayPal">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <img class="payment-img paypal-payment" src="https://www.pastepic.xyz/images/2020/03/03/pay_pal65b5eab2fcbb7421.png">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 div-btn-cash">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="Cash">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="payment-img cash-payment" src="https://www.pastepic.xyz/images/2020/03/03/cash3e374265160bbca9.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="payment-rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 div-btn-visa">
                        <input type="button" class="payment-method" value="MasterCard/Visa">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 visa-payment">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/maestro.png">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/mastercard.png">
                        <img class="payment-img" src="/images/base/visa.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 payment-method-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="payment-method-checkbox" required="">
                    <span>I have read, and I agree to the <a href="https://www.amitours.rent/terms-and-conditions" class="terms-conditions" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set flex-direction : row in payment-row class in your css